# Formula for filtering dates

Tags: sas, proc

I have an issue with my formula to select a date, using PROc SQL in SAS. 
What do I do wrong? Thank you all.
Regards, Geoff

I use this coder:

```
FROM
  VTXBUSS.s
WHERE
  t1.ifrs_stage_date_at_start IS ’ 31DEC2017% ’
ORDER BY
  t1.customer_id,
```

I get a syntax error back. Dates are in this format: 31DEC2017:00:00:00.000000

SAS gives as log:

> ERROR: The value '’'n is not a valid SAS name. WARNING: Apparent
>   invocation of macro ’ not resolved. 45               WHERE
>   t1.ifrs_stage_at_start NOT = t1.ifrs_stage_PROV AND
>   t1.ifrs_stage_date_at_start = ’31DEC2017%’,
>                                                                                                                        _
>                                                                                                                        76 ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, !,
>   !!, &, (, *, **, +, -, '.', /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, AND, EQ, EQT, 
>                 EXCEPT, GE, GET, GROUP, GT, GTT, HAVING, INTERSECT, LE, LET, LT, LTT, NE, NET, NOT, OR, ORDER, OUTER, UNION, ^, ^=, 
>                 |, ||, ~, ~=.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FROM
  VTXBUSS.s
WHERE
  t1.ifrs_stage_date_at_start = '31DEC2017'd
ORDER BY
  t1.customer_id,
```

If you're looking for an specific "datetime", then you should use, for example:

```
FROM
  VTXBUSS.s
WHERE
  t1.ifrs_stage_date_at_start = '31DEC2017:00:00:00.000000'dt
ORDER BY
  t1.customer_id,
```

That is because, when dealing with dates in PROC SQL, you must specify the type of data you're looking for; putting "d" if DATE or "dt" if DATETIME

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter DATETIME values by what DATE they represent you could convert the values to a DATE value.

```
WHERE datepart(t1.ifrs_stage_date_at_start) = '31DEC2017’d
```

Or convert to a specific DATETIME value

```
WHERE intnx('dtday',t1.ifrs_stage_date_at_start,0) = '31DEC2017:00:00’dt
```

Use a range of DATETIME values

```
WHERE t1.ifrs_stage_date_at_start between '31DEC2017:00:00’dt and '01JAN2018:00:00’dt
```

Or possibly convert to a character string

```
WHERE put(t1.ifrs_stage_date_at_start,datetime20.-L) like '31DEC2017:%'
```